Preview Method is not working when using Exoplayer in jetpack compose
I want to build an offline video player app, I create a composable like this,
@UnstableApi
@Composable
fun PlayerScreen(
    exoPlayer: ExoPlayer?,
    playerUiState: PlayerUiState,
    playerOnEvent: (PlayerUiEvent) -> Unit,
    onRotateScreenClick: () -> Unit,
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
){
  // Rest of the code ...
}

now I need a preview function to watch how I am doing, but I cant create a proper preview method for this composable,
I created something like this,
@androidx.annotation.OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PlayerScreenPreview(){
    val context = LocalContext.current

    RXPlayerTheme {
        PlayerScreen(
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build(),
            playerUiState = PlayerUiState(),
            playerOnEvent = {},
            onRotateScreenClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            onBackClick = {}
        )
    }
}

But it's not working! I think I can not make a proper exo-player instance, how can I set up a proper preview method for this?? I just want to make a simple preview method for this composable that's all.

There are 3 Options:
1. Use a Null ExoPlayer:
If the UI doesn't depend heavily on ExoPlayer being non-null, you can pass a null value for exoPlayer in the preview and handle the null case in your PlayerScreen composable.
@UnstableApi
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PlayerScreenPreview() {
    // Mock PlayerUiState for preview purposes
    val mockPlayerUiState = PlayerUiState(
        // Populate with dummy data if needed
    )

    RXPlayerTheme {
        PlayerScreen(
            exoPlayer = null, // Passing null for preview
            playerUiState = mockPlayerUiState,
            playerOnEvent = {},
            onRotateScreenClick = { /* TODO */ },
            onBackClick = {}
        )
    }
}

2. Use a Mock ExoPlayer:
You can create a mock or simple version of ExoPlayer that mimics the behavior without fully relying on the actual implementation. This approach allows you to preview your UI without worrying about the full functionality of ExoPlayer.
@UnstableApi
@Composable
fun PlayerScreenPreview() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Create a simple mock ExoPlayer instance or use a null ExoPlayer for preview
    val mockExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
        // Optionally, configure the mock ExoPlayer with some basic settings
        // You can also leave this as a no-op for preview purposes
    }

    // Mock PlayerUiState for preview purposes
    val mockPlayerUiState = PlayerUiState(
        // Populate with dummy data if needed
    )

    RXPlayerTheme {
        PlayerScreen(
            exoPlayer = mockExoPlayer,
            playerUiState = mockPlayerUiState,
            playerOnEvent = {},
            onRotateScreenClick = { /* TODO */ },
            onBackClick = {}
        )
    }
}


3. Use Dependency Injection: If your app uses dependency injection (DI) frameworks like Hilt or Dagger, you can create a fake ExoPlayer provider for preview purposes.
